# Javascript indexOf behaves differently on server side compared to client side?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, comparison, indexof

Our site runs javascript on .asp and the indexOf function is not behaving as I would expect. See example below (some vars changed for the same of the example. All types are the same however):

```
var SID = "foo";
var getCookie = "foo##%##bar##%##bloo"
var cookieArr = getCookie.split("##%##");

if(cookieArr.indexOf(SID)!=-1){
    console.log("found") //found
} else {
    console.log("not found") //not found
}
```

This works correctly in the console however when run on the server it returns "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the if statement line.

I notice that changing the check to 'cookieArr[0].indexOf(SID)!=-1' resolves to true on the serverside however this is obviously no good as I'm telling it where to look.

If this is a known behaviour, what solution should I use instead to search an array for the presence of a value?

Edit:

Going to use below dirty workaround for now but would still be interested if anyone knows why the above doesn't work

```
function checkArrForString(str,arr){
    for(x=0;x<arr.length;x++){
        if(arr[x]==str){
            return x;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `however when run on the server` - are you using node.js then?

Comment: why you won't use a semicolon in all lines of code?

Comment: That's me re-writing it for the example. Response.Write-ing in the actual script. Our server is configured to run JS on our asp pages (like <%@ Language="javascript" ...[rest of code])

I'm confident it's the indexOf function breaking. Commenting out any code inside of the if and else supports this.

Comment: Which server software are you using?

Comment: That's a good question. Outside of "asp on IIS 6.1" I wouldn't know what to tell you.

Comment: I know in old IE (before version 9), `array.indexOf` didn't exist, so you have to use a polyfill. I wonder if that's at all applicable to some ASP technology.

Comment: And your workaround isn't a bad one at all. I've seen this outperform `indexOf` in several occasions, but it really all depends on the browser. By the way, make sure you have `var x=0;` and use `===`

Comment: If you Google "javascript array indexof polyfill" you should be able to find a code snippet that can detect and fill in the `array.indexOf` method if it's not supported...I'm guessing even on the server

Comment: Unless my memory deceives me I think we may have run into things that old IE's didn't support not working for us in the past. Will try your polyfill solution. Thanks.